# Cannot find module providing package ed25519 in Go language

Tags: go, ed25519

I'm new in Go language. I want to test some code in Go language [some code in Go language](https://github.com/FLAGlab/ssanchez59_Blockchain/blob/master/Data%20Structures/tangle/main.go) by using this command `go run main.go`.

I have this error:
`cannot find module providing package github.com/perlin-network/noise/crypto/ed25519`

I tried to install it using:

```
go get github.com/perlin-network/noise/crypto/ed25519
```

I get this error:

```
go: finding github.com/perlin-network/noise/crypto/ed25519 latest
go: finding github.com/perlin-network/noise/crypto latest
go get github.com/perlin-network/noise/crypto/ed25519: no matching versions for query "latest"
```

I also have tried this:

```
go get -u github.com/perlin-network/noise
```

The error:

```
go: finding github.com/oasislabs/ed25519 latest
go: finding golang.org/x/lint latest
go: finding golang.org/x/xerrors latest
go: finding golang.org/x/crypto latest
go: github.com/oasislabs/ed25519@v0.0.0-20210505154701-76d8c688d86e: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "github.com/oasisprotocol/ed25519"
go: finding golang.org/x/net latest
go get: error loading module requirements
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: github.com/perlin-network/noise uses an old import path (oasislabs has been renamed to oasisprotocol). If removing the -u flag doesn't work you have to ask the perlin-network/noise maintainer to update the imports.

Comment: probably  your  working  directory  is wrong  ,must be in $GOPATH/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently mentioned in [`perlin-network/noise` issue 287](https://github.com/perlin-network/noise/issues/287), since Aug. 2020, without any answer for now (Q2 2021).

An alternative would be to:

- fork the repository  `perlin-network/noise`
- update the dependency in the fork `me/noise`
- use [`go mod replace`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) in your project, to switch repositories.

But all that suggests your own [project uses go mod](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules), so make sure to `go init myproject` first, in order to benefit from those dependencies management feature.
That way, no need to `$GOPATH/src`.